# ipad - Move UITextview to top when keyboard is active

Tags: ipad, keyboard, uitextview

I have `UITextView` in my iPad app and I need to move it to top, when keyboard appears
. Can you help me how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An extract from here :[Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

> Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard When asked to
>   display the keyboard, the system slides it in from the bottom of the
>   screen and positions it over your application’s content. Because it is
>   placed on top of your content, it is possible for the keyboard to be
>   placed on top of the text object that the user wanted to edit. When
>   this happens, you must adjust your content so that the target object
>   remains visible.
>
> Adjusting your content typically involves temporarily resizing one or
>   more views and positioning them so that the text object remains
>   visible. The simplest way to manage text objects with the keyboard is
>   to embed them inside a UIScrollView object (or one of its subclasses
>   like UITableView). When the keyboard is displayed, all you have to do
>   is reset the content area of the scroll view and scroll the desired
>   text object into position. Thus, in response to a
>   UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, your handler method would do the
>   following:
>
> Get the size of the keyboard. Adjust the bottom content inset of your
>   scroll view by the keyboard height. Scroll the target text field into
>   view.